# Sound settings panel empty on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, indicator-sound

After trying to fix my subwoofer problem sound indicator icon is always showing dashes and Sound Settings panel is empty (no audio profiles available, screen attached). Strange that the sound itself is working, I am able to play files. I tried to google but couldn't find the solution. Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Exact same problem.   This alternative solution worked for me, that might help others:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/426648/how-to-reinstall-pulseaudio-ubuntu-12-04/435221#comment1435751_435221

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
My *PulseAudio* daemon wasn't working.I noticed it when I tried to run *pavucontrol* tool.
There was missing shared library libpulse-common (I had older version of this lib installed).

The problem was caused by the fact that I added PPA of Ubuntu Audio Dev team (ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa) to my software sources. I did some reinstallations of indicator-sound and pulseaudio package and somehow libs went out of sync.

How to solve it:

1. Uninstal pulseuadio package `sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio`
2. Remove audio dev team PPA `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa`
3. update source list and get new packages `sudo apt-get update` 
   then `sudo apt-get upgrade`
4. install pulseaudio again `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`
5. reboot `sudo shutdown now -r`