# Missing System Settings after removing some packages

Tags: system-settings

I installed or uninstalled some packages. I do not even remember what I was doing. As a result, now I can't see most of the system settings in settings window. 
Any idea how to solve this problem.

[image]

When I hover mouse over the window title, it shows 'Unknown Application name'
I must have removed something, not sure what :-)

Comment: I encountered the same problem after addressing problems with sound (following a suggestion to remove and reinstall alasbase and pulseaudio - this fixed my sound problem). Reinstalling ubuntu-desktop worked for me (and sound still working)

Comment: Reinstalling ubuntu-desktop solved my sound problem which couldnt be helped by reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio. Thanks a lot

Comment: Unity seems to have a (unjustified?) dependency on `evolution`; running `sudo apt-get purge evolution*` triggers this. To get the System Settings back *without* much *evolution* cruft, I ran `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center --no-install-recommends` afterwards, some evolution-related components get installed and System Settings with all of its icons is back.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov that's exactly the problem: I usually want to slim down my Ubuntu dev machine and remove useless packages which include *evolution* (that is linked with emails in my mind) ... and end up without core Ubuntu features.

Answer (score 316, accepted):

You may have accidentally removed some packages (or some dependencies which caused the package to uninstall). In any case, you may try installing (or re installing) the package `ubuntu-desktop`. Correct any accidental package uninstallation by:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Wow, magic, magic. Love it.
Thanks worked like a charm.

I still don't know what triggered this to happen. I didn't uninstall any package.

Comment: same problem here Indigo and I was just playing with sound... thx cshubhamrao

Comment: Also came a cross this problem wile experiencing sound problems and trying to fix them. Think it happened when I reinstalled alsa-base and pulsesound.

Comment: Excellent. It works..I faced this issue after uninstalling ibus.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center` is probably all you need, not the entire ubuntu-desktop

Comment: @DavidUnderhill yes, but the OP may also have accidentally removed some more packages, installing the `ubuntu-desktop` is sure shot way to fix any more missing packages

Comment: same issue, also started with sound problems as @ThomasK, also reinstalled alsa-base and pulsesound. I just reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and going for a reboot now. Will update upon boot. [UPDATE] ok, this did resolve the Settings issue. My main sound problem still remains, but thats for another thread.

Comment: I met this problem after I issues this command: **apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio**

Comment: I believe the solution by @Thnzrmzwr should be the answer. Sure, reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` should solve the case with missing system settings icons, but it doesn't help if one runs into the problem while *uninstalling* some packages from the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage, like I did.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You saved my day :) I would like to mention that we can install "ubuntu-desktop-minimal" as well to fix this issue. This minimal version downloads just ~60 KB data but ubuntu-desktop will download 500 MB of data.

Comment: Thanks! I had the issue after running `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: Got this after removing mysql* php* mariadb* apache2*

Comment: This fixed my problem after trying just to re-install `unity-control-center` failed.

Comment: This worked for me. I was experimenting with Audacity 3 from PPA and SNAP yesterday (installing and uninstalling) when I noticed the SETTINGS from the top-right menu was gone and unable to adjust my sound settings. Thank you!!

Comment: I keep coming back to this post because I dont remember the command, and because Ubuntu keeps removing my settings. I wish I knew what is going on here. I have not deselected it or removed it on purpose, but it keeps disappearing. Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 103):

Uninstall and then reinstall System Settings (unity-control-center) from the Ubuntu Software Center application.

Or run this command in terminal

1. `sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center`
2. `sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`

Comment: +1 This completely fixes the issue for me without reinstalling all the other stuff that comes with `ubuntu-desktop`, and is the best answer here.

Comment: Did the trick for me, though line #1 said unity-control-center wasn't installed, but second line did it. I've been messing with my 14.04 Ubuntu recently, installed Cinnamon, removed some stuff, and disabled some services, etc, so no clue what cased settings appear like that, but i am pretty sure installing cinnamon played into it some how. Good answer, though -minimalistic and practical

Comment: Awesome, worked for me without reboot.  I think I also lost settings when trying to deal with sound issues.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.

Comment: what's the difference between `unity-control-center` and `gnome-control-center`?

Answer (score 31):

If reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` still doesn't cut it for you, you may be accessing system settings in a wrong way. Try to open them directly from a terminal (rather than a bogus shortcut like I was):

```
gnome-control-center
```

Comment: Thank you for those using the gnome-desktop like me.  Just couldn't remember the name for what needed to be removed and reinstalled.

Answer (score 20):

Yep removing a few programs as suggested BY Ubuntu left settings LOST.

and I had noticed in rem, moving the package, that it also removed gnome-control-center.

Re-installing it solved the problem!
find it in software or alternatively type this in a terminal ...

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Always Trying to help, Mark

Comment: neither one of these solutions solved the settings issue. Only devices tab is shown in settings.

Comment: This was the best answer for me in Ubuntu 20.04.  ubuntu-desktop wanted to download and install the internet.  This just fixed my problem.  It matches this: https://rubelmiah.com/how-to-fix-missing-settings-in-ubuntu/