# System Settings won't load after Ubuntu 14.04 installation

Tags: 14.04, system-settings

Since I installed Ubuntu 14.04, system setting won't load. I click on it in the dash and my mouse indicates it is thinking, but then stops and never loads the system settings. The same is true with Appearance and Display (I haven't tried all options). Help?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `gnome-control-center`. Copy the output and paste it here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to run `unity-control-center` in a terminal, since `gnome-control-center` is not the default in Ubuntu 14.04 anymore.

Comment: Well, at least now I can open the system settings! I would prefer to be able to click the button, but this works. Thanks!

Comment: Did you upgraded from 13.04? Because maybe that's the reason the icon is still pointing at the wrong program. Try sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center && sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-control-center

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do anything, but when I select System Settings from the wheel, the GUI does pop up and works. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 7):

I had to sudo apt-get install unity-control-center for it to work. This was on a fresh install of 14.04.1 LTS, Trusty Tahr

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and this helped:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

found it in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got the solution from both answers, so here you go what I did:

In a new terminal write the following:

```
user@anypc:~$ sudo apt-get update

user@anypc:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

and that was all, gnome settings bring back to normal.

I hope this answer can help somebody with this issue.

Comment: It is already installed, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after **reinstalling** Ubuntu 14 LTS. Tried few reinstallations but the problem persisted and not only the System Settings window was unable to load but the system couldn't restart nor shutdown properly.

After a few hours of research I've remembered that I've seen some people relating the problem to an unmounted device... then I started physically unplugging devices from the machine...

Well, in my case it turned out that the issue is caused by my old webcam. I've unplugged it from the usb port, rebooted and all worked fine. Even I've reinstalled the system without the webcam plugged (because I like to double check) and all worked fine, like before.