# System settings menu Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-settings

Is it normal to have such a reduced system settings menu in Ubuntu 14.04?
No options for keyboard, sounds...

[image: right click on shut down and then selection on system settings]

Comment: sudo: unity-control-center: command not found

Comment: Open a Terminal then run `gksu unity-control-center`. Is it a fresh install of 14.04 or a update from a over version?

Comment: It's an update from 13.10. The result of your sugestion is: (gksu:3186): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed in the comments TuKsn mentioned to use

> gksu unity-control-center

You said this came up with an error.  Instead, try the following:

> sudo apt-get install unity-control-center

If you do not yet have it installed, it will ask if you wish to install it (y/n).  If you do have it installed, which is likely, it will make sure you have the newest version.  Some of the solutions found at [Missing System Settings after removing some packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages) may also help.