# Sound Input device (microphone) not working

Tags: 14.04, microphone, soundcard, dell-vostro

I have recently updated my laptop OS from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04

After updating the OS, my laptop's input device ie., microphone is not working.

Earlier it was working with Ubuntu 12.04.

Also there is no sound input device driver detected

[image: Sound setting]

I am using Dell Vostro 1014.

after running command `$ gstreamer-properties`, output is:

[image: gstreamer-properties]

I think my microphone is working but is not being betected by ubuntu as in above screenshot.

But after running Pulse Audio Sound Control, it shows input sound progress, it means input device is working but not being detected. Even by Sound Recorder.
[image: Pulse Audio Sound Control]

After running `alsamixer` the output is:
[image: alsamixer]

Comment: Updated my question with the output asked for

Comment: gstreamer plugins are already installed, as click the link opens software-center and asks to remove instead of install

Comment: I think there is some setting to select sound input device/profile. But, I don't know where it is.

Comment: What outputs do you have available? Have you checked if your onboard sound card was disabled at the BIOS?

Comment: I have windows 7 parallel to ubuntu. and sound input is working good in windows. If it was disabled in BIOS it must not work with windows as well. This issue is only with Ubuntu

Comment: How did you resolve it? I have the same issue

Comment: I was able to solve this problem once and for all. [Here this solution!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358741/asus-x540s-laptop-internal-microphone-listed-but-not-working)

Comment: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726579/built-in-microphone-not-working-on-acer-aspire) After following this instruction, the headset with the microphone started working. However, the built-in microphone in the laptop still does not work. Generally I have no any input devices in sound settings. Acer Aspire V 15 Nitro - Black Edition.

Answer (score 67):

I had a similar problem - no sound input device driver detected. I used pavucontrol, as explained [in this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19523/42073) and it solved the problem:

- Install pavucontrol: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
- Run:`pavucontrol`
- Go to the **Input Devices** tab
- Click the lock icon to unlock the channels
- Under **Port**, select the correct microphone (front or rear)

Comment: The problem was almost fixed after installing pavucontrol (all devices went mute). One step was left for me and I struggled a lot trying to figure out why I was getting false positives: **Re-plug your I/O sound devices to get them working again**.

Comment: no working with my Plantronics WO350. Its fisible as "Savi Office Base Station Analog Sterio" and looks working, but still nothing to hear

Comment: Thanks a lot, pavucontrol did the trick for me, only install and the mic was working, USB Kungber mic, on Linux Mint 20.2.

Comment: +1 for recommendation of pavucontrol app, which wasn't installed by default in mantic.
It did not fix anything automatically, but allowed me to see: 1) volume input from each device, so I could confirm my mic was working. 2) on the 'recording' tab when google Meet was actually running, it showed that Meet was listening to the wrong mic and let me fix it!

Answer (score 18):

try this in terminal for no sound:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

restart device and check if sound is workin?

if it doesnt do this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio

sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

**The following commands will also remove some important dependencies that may break Ubuntu. Type in the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to reinstall the removed files.**

Restart device and check ..This should probably do the job!

Comment: I tried this, but still nothing happend....

Comment: These commands will also remove some important dependencies that may break Ubuntu. Type in the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` to reinstall the removed files.

Comment: Warning!!!!! what @authentictech said is correct, remember that.

Comment: This commands can potentially break Mint desktop, leaving you with no OS

Answer (score 11):

Open a terminal and issue the command `alsamixer` you will get a screen like this:

[image: alsamixer]

use the right arrow to highlight the Front Microphone

if it's muted as shown above, hit the 'M' key to toggle Mute off.

then use the up arrow to increase the gain (sensitivity) your end result should look similar to this. Hit the Esc key to exit. Your Microphone should now work as advertised.

[image: alsa-gain-up]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to use alsamixer and how to open it for those who don't know. A screenshot would improve your answer as well!!

Comment: @NoTime Answers like this [are not more appropriate as comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments).

Comment: @EliahKagan you are right I should have just put I am unsure if this would solve any issue, already downvoted and flagged as low quality.

Comment: In my case, after running alsamixer, there are only three columns of **Master**,**PCM** and **Beep**. There is no column for microphone.

Comment: it worked! but You can barely hear the sound!

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem.  Solved it like this:

- Run `pavucontrol` from the terminal window.
- Check microphone level and mute switch in tab <kbd>Input Devices</kbd>.
- Open tab <kbd>Recording</kbd>.
- In parallel, start the recording function in the wanted application. E.g. press <kbd>record</kbd> in Audacity or start a test call in Skype.
- In the Recording tab of `pavucontrol`, now a source selection becomes available.  Select the right one.  Worked for me.

To me it is (was) confusing that the source selector is not always present in `pavucontrol`.

Comment: @JuanAntonio, Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/873053/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 6):

Goto PulseAudio volume control --> Configuration, choose "Analog Stereo Duplex" under the Profile section.

Restart your machine.

*Tried in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

If you don't see your `Microphone` in the `Port` selection under the `input devices` in `pavucontrol`:
use `pavucontrol` -> configuration -> built_in Audio. Check if you have `* Output + * Input` choosen in your profile, otherwise your microphone isn't shown in the `input devices` section and cannot be used.

Answer (score 3):

The following might work for you:

1. Run `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` on terminal (if you have no access to a graphical interface in the moment, use `sudo nano` instead of `gksudo gedit`.
2. Add `options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1` or `position_fix=2` to the end of the file.
3. Reboot

Sources: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1893142 and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/PositionReporting

Comment: The symptoms for that are listed as crackling audio.. the question's issue is with no audio at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

add this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel index=0 model=laptop-dmic
```

Comment: This made a microphone unit show up in Sound settings ("Internal Microphone Built-In Audio"), but it is stuck at 0% volume and greyed out. I'm on Mint 20, i.e., Ubuntu 20.04, and running a Dell Inspiron 7708 laptop.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, the internal mic shows up, I can change volume, but it registers no sound.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found the solution after I upgraded to 16.04, but I think it works on 14.04 too! In Skype click "Open PulseAudio Volume Control". From there on move to "Input Devices" and change the Port. By some miracle my microphone started working after I changed my port to "Microphone (unplugged)". Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For me everything looked correct, input device was selected correctly however I was unable to use the inner or the external mic. I solved it by enabling the webcam using the **Fn** keys. Apparently they are enabled and disabled by the same **Fn** key.

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem on 14.04, sound input source was blank in the 'Sound Settings'.
I did the following, what did the trick is installing 'Audacity', for more info check the following [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AudioCapture)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Comment: Doind this somehow completely screwed with my system. Now I don't even have sound settings or a sound icon on the panel. Fixed it after reading http://askubuntu.com/q/453440/48105 and reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Purging packages should be done with great trepidation. It can kill things that you'll have a lot of trouble getting back.