# gnome-control-center missing options

Tags: 12.04, pulseaudio, alsa, gnome-control-center

I was having issues with microphone input and followed advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508221/sound-input-device-microphone-not-working/508234#508234?newreg=4494a5b1cc30431a928428d3f2a4a8f1) to fix `alsa-base`. In doing so I have lost a number of options from `gnome-control-center`. Most people with the issue found that [reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` helped](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages). However, when I open `gnome-control-center` I continue to get the following error:

```
$ sudo gnome-control-center 

** (gnome-control-center:23520): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher landscape-client-settings (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:23520): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)
```

Prior to reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`, there were more errors (which looked similar) but these two remain. I have also reinstalled `unity-control-center`, `ubuntuone*`, `landscape-client` and more. Nothing seems to help.

Notably, `gnome-control-center` "cannot find display information", despite the display icon being present.

Running Ubuntu 12.04 on a 2011 Macbook. Thank you in advance for your help.