# Ubuntu does not recognize external microphone

Tags: drivers, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, hda-intel

Good morning!

On Ubuntu 17.10 my microphone is not found.
My Sound card is ALC295, driver intel-hda, and everything works fine, internal speaker and microphone, except my external microphone. I've attached an headset to it, but it just uses the audio output, not the microphone.

I've already tried several fixes, everything that I could find on the internet, but I was not able to get any positive result. I tried e.g.:

- trying overrides with `hdajackretask`
- adding my soundcard model to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
- muting one of the stereo channels via `pavucontrol`
- installing the Realtek drivers, but didn't work as they are too old and unmaintained

I tried everything I could find via Google or via the askubuntu search, but nothing did work. Does anyone have a tip or a solution for this problem?

If it helps, my Notebook is an Acer Spin 5 SP513-52N.

Screenshot of my hdajackretask configuration: 
[image: hdajackretask screenshot]

Comment: I assume your system has a combo jack and you are using a headset with a built in microphone that has a 4 pole plug. Have you checked the microphone is working on another device? (even a cell phone).  Can you post a hdajackretask screenshot that shows the pin configuration?

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's entirely correct! I've added a `hdajackretask` screenshot. And yes, I've already checked the headset: Windows 10 is also running on that notebook, it recognizes the headset (including the microphone) without any problems. Also, I tried other headsets, but Ubuntu still does not recognize their microphones..

Comment: Maybe check if my answer on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508221/sound-input-device-microphone-not-working/873053#873053) solves your problem.

Comment: @oscar1919 Thank you, I just tried it, but unfortunately there's no new option, just the two options for the built-in microphone.

Comment: In `hdajackretask`, try overriding both microphones at the same time.  Set one mic to "Internal mic" and the other mic to "Not Connected" then click "apply now". And of course try both possible configurations. It appears `hdajackretask` is seeing the ALC295 correctly. Also the `snd_hda_intel` driver is the correct driver to use.

Comment: @stumblebee Unfortunately no success. Regardless of which Pin I overrided, both time the input came from the internal microphone. Seems to be like both canals of the stereo input..