# Mic doesn't work on linux

Tags: 18.04, microphone

My mic doesn't get detected. I've tried what's said in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508221/sound-input-device-microphone-not-working) and **it worked yesterday but after rebooting I have the same problem again** and it is not working (accessing to pavucontrol). I also tried checking **alsamixer** and everything seems fine and the mic is unmuted.

I use Ubuntu 18.04

This is my data:

```
s@pc:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xd1320000 irq 129
s@pc:~$ lspci | grep -i audio 
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
```