# Realtek high definition audio

Tags: sound, microphone, realtek

I have an Acer Aspire ES-15. When I plug a Jack to the laptop (On windows 10) Came up a window where I can select if the device i pluged in is a microphone, a headphone or a speaker. (My audio card is a Realtek HD audio) Now I have only Ubuntu for OS and my PC does not recognize if I connect a microphone to the only jack port that has.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this a try...

- Install pavucontrol: sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
- Run: sudo pavucontrol
- Go to the "Input Devices" tab
- Click the lock icon to unlock the channels
- Under "Port", select the correct microphone (front or rear)

Found in this thread here:
[Sound Input device (microphone) not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508221/sound-input-device-microphone-not-working)

Comment: I want to connect an external microphone to the computer's jack port because I'm a musician and the Pavucontrol doesn't recognize that it's connected and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

5.1 Realtek High Definition Audio is not supported in ubuntu, only gets stereo! soundcluster z is not supported in ubuntu. Well, in ubuntu 22.10 soundblaster z is supported but the sound comes out of the wrong speakers in my logitech 5.1 system. Tried to find a new 5.1 sound card that is certainly supported in linux, but after days of google searching I gave up, clearly people in linux don't use 5.1 sound!!! (irony)