# No microphone in Ubuntu 18.04 on HP elitebook

Tags: 18.04, sound, alsa

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my new HP elitebook 850 G6 after erasing windows. I could not get audio input part working though..
Fn F8 key is orange all the time and this is how settings looks like.

[image: sound]

I installed pavucontrol, but that didn't change anything. What I have noticed is that I cannot check "set as fallback" permanently.

[image: pavucontrol]

Also tried editing `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` by adding

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Sound control still does not recognize any microphone

Comment: Maybe check my answer on this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/508221/sound-input-device-microphone-not-working/873053#873053.  Some controls only show up in pavucontrol when you already started a program which needs mic input.

Comment: didn't help..problem is that input devices tab still show "Microphone (unplugged)" even though i could choose a input from Recording tab

Comment: @senseiwu - I have a similar issue w/ hp elitebook 840 - very frustrating - added a 50pt bounty - post a response if you figured it out to collect

Comment: @meyerson only workaround was to use a bluetooth headset such as plantronic or JBL. No solution to make built in microphone work yet

Comment: @senseiwu - yes that what I did as well - which led me into another sad Ubuntu ditch - the sound and mic quality of HFP (hands free protocol?, as opposed to A2DP) is dismal, thats why I use arch on my other laptop - the internal mic works, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1838151 for more context

Comment: IIRC the Fn Key switch is independent from the OS - have you tried booting in the BIOS and pressing the Fn+Key switch ? Its also worth checking out all the BIOS options, since HPs Elitebooks series is for enterprise use, there are **a ton of options** you would not normally see in a BIOS. I just checked [the BIOS manual for HP](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06399361) and there seems to be an option to enable/disable it there (page 40)

Comment: @meyerson you should check out my comment, the underlying issue is probably not Ubuntu related and hopefully easily fixed

Comment: @RobertRiedl - will give this a try later in the day - thanks, worth looking into

Comment: @meyerson had a chance to check out the bios ? any change ?

Comment: Check out this thread: [Microphone not working in Ubuntu 18.04 on new HP Spectre X360 Convertible 15 laptop](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1840725). There are plenty of solutions. Maybe one of them will help you resolve your problem. Have a close look at answers #3 and #30

Comment: whats worth mentioning is that f8 key (mic) is permanently yellow

Comment: @RobertRiedl yes i did. I think by now I am pretty much familiar with all the BIOS setting of HP ;-) as sadly, wifi adopter also stopped working (after an update I believe). Sadly, no solutions worked there either. Symptoms are similar - hardware button disabled and F10 is orange all the time - so no level of tweaking in Ubuntu is gonna help

Comment: @senseiwu this si weird, especially if other things - like your wifi - also stopped working.. maybe there is an underlying hardware issue..

Comment: may be sound silly but i lived that issue with my laptop just now and ths micropohone unplugged issue solved with unplug external speaker from 3.5 mm jack :) however i couldnt find a way to work with speaker an my laptop's internal mic.

Comment: I also have same problem. I fixed it by following below link.
https://gist.github.com/Therises/d2e91c81af1574f9069635d520fdc7ec

Answer (score 0):

I have installed dconf-editor and dconf
after start of the gui the search-function is active and you could use the keyboard.
The keyword "volume" drives to a button named "use-mediakeys" on or off?