# No sound in Ubuntu 14.04 after HDMI detatch

Tags: 14.04, unity, sound, alsa

I was using my TV as a monitor connected to my lenovo laptop, through a HDMI connection, manually changing the sound sink in system options. Then I shutdown the system and then unplugged the HDMI, when for the next time I started Ubuntu, the sound dissapeared. The sound is not present only on my user profile (on the Guest is everything ok). I belive that the system somehow 'forgot' to reset to the internal speakers of my laptop.
I've tried solutions with writing a /etc/defaults/sound.conf, or using alsamixer or even re-installing the alsa-base pulseaudio. Nothing helped.
Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please try to connect the TV again, System settings - sound, set it to internal speakers, disconnect TV.  Please let us know if this helps...

Answer (score 2):

That was not the whole problem as I see now. You see, after the re-installation of the alsa drivers, there was no 'sound indicator' in the system tray. I tried to access system options but... there were only some of them, like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages). I needed to re-install the unity-control-center and that did the trick. Finally,

> Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please try to connect the TV again, System settings - sound, set it to internal speakers, disconnect TV. Please let us know if this helps... –  Fabby

Yeah, that was the final part, which did the trick. My sound is up and running again - Thanks for help :) I hope this will be a good solution for others, who encounter such obstacles.