# Problem after upgrade from 14.04.02 to 15.04

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

I have a weird problem after upgrade my ubuntu 14.04 to 15.05..
The words in the whole system are like the image below, anyone has/had the problem or know how can I fix it?

I don't know if it is a problem with my graphical video board, it is a GForce 310 M.

http://imageshack.com/a/img673/3411/yEjHzn.png

Comment: does the behavior persist if you boot a 15.04 live usb ?

Comment: Try this post may be it help you 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages

Comment: @OrganicMarble I created the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf like your link describe and now it solved my problem, thanks!