# Missing Security & Privacy after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, security, privacy

After a successful upgrade from Vivid 15.04 to Wiley 15.10 everything is working 100% fine. But I discovered I am missing the "security & privacy" option in system settings. It doesnt appear in the dash or HUD either its missing here too. Any ideas how I might get this back?

Comment: me also, i lost settings as well. But after reboot attempt looks  it appeared  again. Try to look into `/var/log/syslog` if you can see something.

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/q/453440/178596) (*relevant but not a duplicate*) may solve your issue (basically reinstall the default packages for your desktop)

Answer (score 5):

Try to installing it for control center

```
sudo apt-get install activity-log-manager-control-center
```