# unity-control-center not working in i3wm on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, i3-wm, gnome-control-center

I am using i3wm desktop environment on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Everything was fine on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Now when I use `unity-control-center` I see only the following settings:

1. Personal > Language Support
2. Hardware > Printers
3. System > Software & Updates

Where are the rest of the controls? I tried using the `gnome-control-center`. Still nothing better.

But if I use the Unity desktop environment everything works. I suppose, I need to run something before calling `unity-control-center`. What am I missing?

Please explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For **Gnome** Ubuntu:

Set `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` to `GNOME` and you're good to go:

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

For **Unity** Ubuntu:

Set `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` to `Unity` and you're good to go:

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity unity-control-center
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you also know how to make unity-control-center work? I tried XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity. Didn't work.

Comment: Interesting, And XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity makes the unity-control-center work. Sorry I was trying with $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP.

Comment: On Ubuntu 23.04 I'm not being able to open the gnome-control-center unless I set this XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP variable. Awesome this still helped me!

Answer (score 4):

I'll complement the answers above with an explanation to why this happens when you're using i3wm.

When you install and use i3 as your *windows manager*, i3 automatically sets the current desktop variable to **i3**. You can check it by doing:

```
echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

Which returns `i3`

Ubuntu native programs do not work well if this environmental variable is set to a different value than `Unity` or `Gnome` depending on your Ubuntu distro.

To fix it you can simply set XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP to your desktop environment.

On Gnome:

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME; gnome-control-center
```

On Unity:

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity; unity-control-center
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to following CSaratakij's answer, I had to install some packages I accidentally uninstalled:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

You could also do (installs less packages):

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Source: [Missing System Settings after removing some packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages#453441)

unity-control-center still doesn't work for me, but gnome-control-center works fine.