# Move launcher from one monitor to another in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, launcher, display

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on a HP Desktop with two monitors. The launcher is currently located on the left edge of the right hand monitor which is very inconvenient. How do I move it to the left edge of the left monitor?

I am able to move it to the bottom with:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
```

But I would like to move it to the left edge of the left monitor.

Comment: The ancient bug report says fix released, and OP says it didn't help, so I don't think we should be closing this against that

Answer (score 4):

Go to **System Settings > Screen Display**

Find **Launcher placement** and select the display you want to put the launcher on.

[image]

Other than that you could personalize your unity interface with Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: I don’t have a 'Display' option on 'System Settings'. I have a 'Screen Display' option but this doesn’t have a 'Launcher placement' option.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24v8j1z&s=9#.WMmQl0d4FhE

Comment: i think this might be your problem, check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages#453441 after that you should be able to do it the way i told you before.

Comment: I have just tried this and uninstalled the system settings then reinstalled but this didn’t provide any more options.

Comment: @AlexanderPeace It's at Screen Display at it should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb7jf.png