# system settings disapeared from launcher

Tags: system, settings

After restart my pc this morning I found that there was no sound system.
First thing I did was:
sudo alsa force reload

That didn't solve the problem:

Next I did the following:

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio

and again:

sudo alsa force-reload

I have sound system again but something strange happened:

I don't have the "system settins" icon on the launcher and when I access the system settings on the top right corner  icon I see only 3 sections:

Personal
hardware
software update

What can I do now to recover all the system settings ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

[Missing System Settings after removing some packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages)

Majority users faced this problem after uninstalling/re-installing sound packages. Some dependencies might have been accidentally removed. You can rectify the situation by first installing the unity control center.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

If this doesn't solve the issue for you, then reinstall the ubuntu desktop package

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```