# Where is my settings tool?

Tags: settings, tools

I updated my Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 and I not find the settings.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

I tried several things. I go "wifi-settings and no work". So I go "account-settings and no work". My settings in ubuntu no is. Where is?

Comment: @Shayan I tried that just. Also check second comand and this is Active.

Comment: I searched more about your questions, it seems you're missing the Settings app? try this: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` https://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages

Comment: Yeap. I resolve problem with `sudo apt install gnome-control-center
`

Comment: @sebacc Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center && reboot
```