# No audio working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

[PulseAudio uses up a lot of processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGJEl.jpg) when I open up a video on YouTube or play something on Rhythmbox. The YouTube video never loads, and the music on Rhythmbox starts skipping like a minute every second.

I tried `sudo killall pulseaudio` then running `pulseaudio` logged in as root. I get the below error messages after a little bit:

```
root@aa-ul:~$ pulseaudio
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
W: [pulseaudio] alsa-mixer.c: Your kernel driver is broken: it reports a volume range from 0 to 0 which makes no sense.
W: [pulseaudio] alsa-mixer.c: Your kernel driver is broken: it reports a volume range from 0 to 0 which makes no sense.
```

Here's a link to the [output of `pulseaudio -v`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8133786/) that I killed when it took a while.

Output of `aplay -l`:

```
aa@aa-ul:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: ALC269 Analog [ALC269 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

How can I get audio to work? I tried `apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio` but it didn't work.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit over 3.13.0-34-generic, and the system is up-to-date.

Here's the output of an ALSA information script that contains the output of some useful commands: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=d43a5b6bca9e599edad228c9c34f3f46987214be

Comment: "Your kernel driver is broken" suggests a problem with the kernel; what one are you using?

Comment: 3.13.0-34-generic. I've added extra information to the question.

Comment: Did you try updating? I'm already using 3.13.0-35-generic, uname -r says, which means there's a newer one out.

Comment: Yup, everything is up to date, which repositories are you using?

Comment: I found the solution in this question: [How to reinstall PulseAudio (Ubuntu 12.04)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/426648/how-to-reinstall-pulseaudio-ubuntu-12-04). I removed `pulseaudio`, ran `rm -r ~/.config/pulse`, reinstalled `pulseaudio`, ran `sudo alsa force-reload` and restarted. Note: removing `pulseaudio` removed `ubuntu-desktop`, so I also installed it when reinstalling `pulseaudio`. Anyone facing this issue could probably try removing the `~/.config/pulse` only and restarting.