# Cannot select output device from sound indicator

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio, indicator

Using 15.04 on a Lenovo Flex 14, new install.  Chrome had no sound,while FF and chrome did.  to get it working,

sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound

then sudo apt-get install pulseaudio indicator-sound

This got sound working in Chrome.  When you click on the sound indicator the dialogue box that comes up allowing you to choose your output device, change volume level etc, is missing a significant portion of the graphics.  I can not chose between output devices, for example.  I can still open Rhythm Box and control the sound output level.

I reinstalled pulse audio and the indicator but to no avail.

Is there any way to restore this?

Thanks

garyk

Comment: I tried purging and reinstalling pulse following the instructions here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/426648/how-to-reinstall-pulseaudio-ubuntu-12-04   The sound graphics show no change.  I have the same issue with bluetooth.  In the Unity panel the graphics are incomplete as well when you select Bluetooth Settings