# connection to pulse audio failed lubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio

Im kind of new to lubuntu 16.04
Computer model P755 S5120 Toshiba

After an update im getting error saying connection to pulse audio failed
Volume works correctly from computer speakers but since pulse audio interface doesnt work wont be able to connect HDMI

I have tried uninstalling pulse audio and reinstalling but didn't work
ran this command `pulseaudio --start`
getting error `[pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.`

Heres my screenshot 
http://www.mediafire.com/view/89wg76rc9vy54nm/2016-06-29-154621_1366x768_scrot.png

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In your screenshot you are using Windows XP, but in your description you say you are using Lubuntu 16.04. If you are using Windows XP, this question is not about Ubuntu. Please flag your question to be closed or to be migrated to SuperUser. Please do not cross-post unless you delete your question. If you are using Lubuntu 16.04 than please upload a screenshot of that.

Comment: @CollDue96 It appears to be a Windows XP theme for Lubuntu; it's not quite the same as actual Windows XP, the start menu has a Tux penguin, and there are shortcuts on the desktop to Lubuntu Software Center and LXTerminal

Comment: Ok whoops. I should have looked more carefully. At least I didn't flag it. :D

Comment: I know its kind of confusing but its lubuntu 16.04 with windows xp theme

Comment: The error message in your screenshot suggests you run 'start-pulseaudio-x11'

Comment: I tried that in terminal but im getting this error Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

Answer (score 5):

I was finally able to solve my problem by following this thread

[How to reinstall PulseAudio (Ubuntu 12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426648/how-to-reinstall-pulseaudio-ubuntu-12-04)

I used all the commands listed on the first answer and it worked and for people who have trouble with this could possibly find the solution.