# Dummy Output after upgrade to 16.10

Tags: sound, 16.10

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10 and after that the soundcard stopped working. It doesn't show the as before but only showing Dummy Output.

Output from `lspci` show the following:

```
0:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V (rev 31)
02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
```

`aplay` shows the following:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
```

My motherboard is a Asus Z170 pro-gaming.
Already added options `snd-hda-intel model=auto` to the `alsa.conf` without any success.

## Update 16.10.2016

Also tried

- `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`
- `sudo apt install alsa-base* indicator-sound* libcanberra-pulse* osspd* osspd-pulseaudio* pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth* pulseaudio-module-x11* unity-control-center* unity-control-center-signon*`

This made the icons get back, but still only "dummy output"

Comment: did you tried a real shutdown , not reboot?

Comment: Try reinstalling pulseaudio

Comment: see this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/426648/how-to-reinstall-pulseaudio-ubuntu-12-04#435221

Comment: Now the system notification icon is gone. But it still shows the dummy output. So sadly did not help anything.

Comment: Just today under 16.04 a Dummy Output device showed up and rebooting got rid of it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix sadly does not fix this issue.

Comment: What's the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`?

Comment: I also have this problem. Once a `sudo alsa force-reload` fixed it, but other times I have to reboot. What the heck? Dell xps laptop here.

Answer (score 2):

I used to face similar problem and needed to run `sudo alsa force-reload` every time I start my computer. Then identified the processes that ALSA stops to reload it from the PIDs shown in the output.

Used `sudo pstree -p` prior to reloading ALSA so that I can find out the process names corresponding to the PIDs. Started uninstalling the packages related to those possibly problematic processes.

Finally found uninstalling `squeezelite-pa` solved my problem.