# Sound is not working properly in ACER ASPIRE 4736Z

Tags: 16.04, sound, acer, aspire

As I posted this question, the Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS I am using is freshly/newly reinstalled, little problem is that the sound is not working properly, when I tried to test it out, **System Settings > Sound > Speakers (Built-in Audio) > Test Sound**, then I test both the **Front left and Right left**, here are the results:

- **Front left** - working but not working as it should be, I do not know the specific term but the sound it's creating is not good in the ears.
- **Front right** - not working at all.

What do I need to do make the speakers works?

Answer (score 0):

I think, your speakers are broken. If not try installing **PulseAudio** sound driver. It compatible with every hardware.

Comment: it improved the **Front left** a little bit.

Comment: Please how can we install this driver...?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/426648/how-to-reinstall-pulseaudio-ubuntu-12-04