# Fail to connect to bluetooth headset on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth

Since this morning I have been unable to connect my bluetooth headset to my ubuntu Gnome 16.04 machine. It was working fine just yesterday.

Now whenever I try to pair/connect to my computer, it pairs but fails to connect.

message on `/var/log/syslog` file:

```
Mar  5 14:59:28 Mijolnir bluetoothd[833]: a2dp-sink profile connect failed for 00:25:DB:70:00:F2: Protocol not available
```

output of `[bluetooth]# info <MAC>`:

```
Device 00:25:DB:70:00:F2
    Name: G-CUBE BH-860
    Alias: G-CUBE BH-860
    Class: 0x240404
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    RSSI: -50
```

output of `[bluetooth]# show`:

```
Controller A0:88:69:CC:48:9E
    Name: Mijolnir
    Alias: Mijolnir
    Class: 0x000000
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0525
    Discovering: yes
```

output to `rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Can someone show me the light on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: multiple times. I run dualboot, so I also went onto windows to check if it might be general issue, but everything works fine.. in fact, bluetooth on ubuntu works fine.. I just successfully connected to my phone.. but my headset just wont connect anymore, like I said, yesterday it was all good. Since nothing changed on the headset, i am hoping some config on ubuntu might have changed

Comment: Last time I had this issue the problem turned out to be that my headphones were still connected to my iPhone. Once I turned off the phone's Bluetooth I could connect the headphones to the computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So after some digging, I have found that there were problems with pulseaudio and bluez.. something to do with the protocols which were delegated to gstreamer but I can't seem to find the post where I read this. something must have broken with the latest update, because I had my bluetooth working fine the day before

Anyway.. what solved this for me was purging pulseaudio and reinstalling it. as per [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/435221/293349):

```
$ sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
$ sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio*
$ sudo alsa force-reload
$ pavucontrol
```

And reboot.

I had tried purging and reinstalling only pulseaudio bluetooth module. But that had not solved the issue for me. So in the step where I installed pulseaudio, note I installed `pulseaudio*`. This installs all pulseaudio modules, including bluetooth.
You don't actually need to run pavucontrol, as you may need to install it. All it does for us here, effectively, is restart pulseaudio. I decided to install it because it has more utilities and setting options for pulseaudio.

[The post](https://askubuntu.com/a/435221/293349) suggests some more tweaking. but pairing/connection problems were solved for me after the reboot, so I never got to that.

A previous issue I had with pulseaudio presented itself right after I reinstalled it, where a2dp would not be recognised. If it happens to you, check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/775524/293349) for a fix.

Everything is working as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest removing the device from the settings and after that adding the device using bluetoothctl.
Ps:Remember to copy paste the device mac address before removing it

```
bluetoothctl
scan on
pair <mac>
```