# Can't connect bluetooth headset

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio

For some reason, I can't connect to my headset anymore, when I click on it in the bluetooth setting it's "loading" for some time and then sets back to the "Not setup" state.

I wasn't able to find anything at the `/var/logs/` (There is no `syslog` directory, idk why)

Maybe it's because some time ago I installed pulseaudio, and it caused that.

I've already followed the instructions of this thread's answer - [Fail to connect to bluetooth headset on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012164/fail-to-connect-to-bluetooth-headset-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Some command results:

```
sudo pactl list short | grep -i bluetooth
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Comment: Please edit question to include result from terminal for pactl list short | grep -i bluetooth

Comment: @GopalS done...?