# My Sennheiser HD 350BT can't connect to Ubuntu PC

Tags: bluetooth, headset

So i've tried every single thing on the internet and still my Sennheiser HD 350BT can't connect to my Ubuntu computer. How can i connect my headset to my computer? I'm a newbie so please comment any neccessary info and i'll provide them.

Edit:
My phone can connect to PC without any problem.

I've tried to install blueman and it didn't helped me. Tried as [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012164/fail-to-connect-to-bluetooth-headset-on-ubuntu-16-04) suggested and still doesn't work.

By doesn't work i mean with blueman it fails and with Ubuntu's bluetooth it doesn't connect eventhough i've clicked several times.

Comment: One assumes that you mean you are unable, using Bluetooth, to pair your headset with your Ubuntu system. Your question should note whether or not your other BT devices pair with your Ubuntu system properly.

Comment: Please describe what you have tried and how it has failed.

Comment: Edited question, let me know if any info is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this exact headset and this is the process I followed to connect. First, be certain that the headset is fully charged. I usually charge mine overnight every night.

Next, in settings, turn on bluetooth. Now, on the headphones, press and hold the ‘connect’ button for three seconds. The blue LED should flash several times indicating that the power is on and, a few moments later, that is it connected. You will see confirmation in Settings > Bluetooth:

> HD350BT     Connected

Finally, under Settings, select Sound. Under Output Device use the drop-down menu, select Headphone-HD350BT. Put the headphones on and test.

You should be all set.

Comment: The thing is i can't connect headset to computer at all. When i click the headset under Bluetooth>Devices i doesn't connect.

Comment: Have you already confirmed that the headset is charged, turned  on and trying to connect? What is the blue LED telling you?

Comment: It works with my phone. And blue LED turns on when powered.

Comment: Please run: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep 350BT` Next, edit your question to show the result. If the output is lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: The only place i can paste is this: https://gist.github.com/YarkinGulacti/a6e698c64b05003afa9dd36fd64f79fe.

Comment: It appears that you didn't include the entire command. You've posted thousands of lines and *none* of them, that I can find, include the term '350BT.' If you ran the command as I requested, then '350BT' doesn't appear anywhere.  How about: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i blue` For comparison, my syslog shows: "bluetoothd[971]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_XX_1B_66_EB_3B_XX/sep1/fd9: fd(47) ready" where XX_1B_66_EB_3B_XX is the redacted MAC address of my headset.

Comment: Here is the link of the command result: https://justpaste.it/66q3k

Comment: What we see here are many errors and exceptions running *blueman*. Is it possible to NOT start blueman and try to connect only with Settings > Blutooth and then gather the errors again? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i blue `

Comment: Basiclly issue was i didn't put headsets in pairing mode and that's why it wasn't connecting to PC. Thanks a lot for your helps Sir.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me, founded in "Sennheiser Smart Control" mobile app.

The two highlighted buttons are correct in the picture 1, but in the text below picture it says on/off button and multi-function button, while it's voice assistant button and multi-function buttons. (part 9 and 10 from the manual / Picture 2 and 3)

I just hold both buttons and select Pair in blueman-manager application, should works with default Bluetooth panel in Settings.

Picture 1:

[image: Picture 1]

Picture 2:

[image: Picture 2]

Picture 3:

[image: Picture 3]