# Speakers/sound not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, speakers

The speakers on Windows work fine, but not on Ubuntu (22.04). Also, the wired headphones work, but fail to connect wireless headphones via Bluetooth. From [Fail to connect to bluetooth headset on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012164/fail-to-connect-to-bluetooth-headset-on-ubuntu-16-04) I am thinking the problem might be with `pulseaudio`, but the proposed solution did not work for me.

I tried purging pulseaudio and reinstalling it, tried toggling alsamixer options, editing /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, using `sudo setfacl -m u:$USER:rw /dev/snd/*` as suggested in other posts. Nothing seems to work for me.

I'm not sure if it's relevant, but every time I switch from Windows to Ubuntu I have to change SATA configuration to AHCI.

Here's some further information:

[image: Sound settings]

`$ aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC294 Analog [ALC294 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`$ cat /proc/asound/modules`

```
0 snd_hda_intel
1 snd_hda_intel
```

`$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Comet Lake PCH cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 166
    Memory at c5418000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at c5100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at c5080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
```

`$ systemctl --user status pipewire-session-manager.service`

```
 pipewire-media-session.service - PipeWire Media Session Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire-media-session.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-08-22 23:29:24 CEST; 9min ago
   Main PID: 2027 (pipewire-media-)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18837)
     Memory: 4.2M
        CPU: 84ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire-media-session.service
             └─2027 /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session

Started PipeWire Media Session Manager.
ms.core: error id:25 seq:292 res:-16 (Device or resource busy): can't create node: Device or resource busy
```