# Error - Package 'pulseaudio' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, software-installation, pulseaudio

I have just recently upgraded to **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Dell Vostro 15** laptop. I had some problems related to pulseaudio, so I ran these commands as it is shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/435221/1013762)

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After executing these commands I ran `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio` and even tried running `sudo apt install pulseaudio` but these errors occured :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pulseaudio is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'pulseaudio' has no installation candidate
```

Any ideas how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a long shot

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Go to Tab updates and activate bionic-updates and bionic-security.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work for me as the bionic-updates and bionic-security checkboxes were disabled so I couldn't activate them. Is there any way that I can enable them ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rhuancarlos/c4d3c0cf4550db5326dca8edf1e76800  default bionic and https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories