# PulseAudio pavucontrol is stuck on "Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait."

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

system Information

"System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4
wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal"

So, here's the story here. I checked the logs and found a security issue related to PulseAudio.

This is what it started off with.
"A start job for unit UNIT has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 91 and the job result is failed."

and then the security issue right after:
"Failed to create secure directory (/home/[USERNAME]/.config/pulse): No such file or directory"

This occured over and over during each boot.

so i looked up this guide and followed it...
[How to reinstall PulseAudio (Ubuntu 12.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426648/how-to-reinstall-pulseaudio-ubuntu-12-04)

the guide completed successfully, and after, my GNOME desktop theme decided to take over the Linux Mint Cinnamon. I'm fine with that.

here's a workup of detected cards:

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
" 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
HDA Intel PCH at 0xdd340000 irq 136
1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
HDA NVidia at 0xdf080000 irq 17
2 [Hea            ]: USB-Audio - Corsair VOID RGB USB Gaming Hea
Cosair Corsair VOID RGB USB Gaming Hea at usb-0000:00:14.0-6, full speed
3 [XFi            ]: SB-XFi - Creative X-Fi
Creative X-Fi 20K2 Unknown"

And The Test of the active device was a success. heard it loud and clear...

aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav

"Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono"

I ran pavucontrol via terminal it tries to connect and it hangs.

Comment: Well Mint is not Ubuntu. Go to the their forums and ask. Don't get me wrong - I like Mint a lot - but we need to focus on Ubuntu - and Mint has other packages than Ubuntu has

Answer (score 0):

All the issues about Pulse Audio in Ubuntu 20.04 can be solved by replacing Pulse Audio server with Pipewire server in 20.04 or 21.04. I also had lots of sound issues during install. Maybe you have this issue because you tried to fix it. There are many ways of installing it, just sharing what worked for me, but for some there is one line more, but better not to put it if it works.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
sudo apt install pipewire gstreamer1.0-pipewire libspa-0.2-bluetooth libspa-0.2-jack pipewire-audio-client-libraries
sudo touch /etc/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user --now enable pipewire pipewire-pulse
systemctl --user mask pulseaudio
```

If it doesn't work add:

```
systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session.service
```

But I didn't need it.
And you don't need the cp part for it to work.

Information comes from this blogposts:

- [How to Install The Latest PipeWire via PPA in Ubuntu 20.04, 21.04](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/install-latest-pipewire-ppa-ubuntu-20-04/)
- [How to Enable PipeWire Audio Service to Replace PulseAudio in Ubuntu 21.04](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/enable-pipewire-audio-service-ubuntu-21-04/)